# Passing property between threads in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In J meter, I am unable pass property from thread 1 to thread 2 if there is JDBC request in thread 1. If there is no JDBC request, property is getting passed from thread 1  to thread 2. Any specific  reason for this, Any changes i need to do? kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Passing values between Thread Groups is not something you should be normally doing, I would recommend reconsidering the design of your JMeter script so it would not be required
2. There are several ways of passing values between different thread groups starting from using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__P() functions combination](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P), using interim [CSV](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) files,  and ending up with [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/), they all should work irrespective of presence/absence of the JDBC test elements in this or that Thread Group

When anything goes wrong in the absolute majority of cases JMeter will print something to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), first of all check it for any warnings/errors and if they are not there - check the variables/properties values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)